# Can not disable autoneg via ethtool

Tags: nic, ethtool

I want to disable the `auto-negotiation` feature of NIC, I run the following command

```
$sudo ethtool -s ens1f0 speed 10000 duplex full autoneg off
```

Then I check if it takes effect via `ethtool ens1f0`:

```
Settings for ens1f0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

The `autoneg` is still on, why it does not work?

**Update 2020/8/22**

My NIC is `82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb`, and I found that 10GBASE-T link's `auto-neg` feature can be off in some cases.

1. It's strange that the two ports of a NIC have different `autoneg` states. I'm really confused about this.

```
Settings for ens1f0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes

Settings for ens1f1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

2. When the port does not connect with a peer, the `autoneg` is off

```
Settings for ens1f1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Other
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable autonegotiation on a 10GBASE-T link. The 802.3 standard indicates that [autonegotiation is mandatory](http://noahdavids.org/self_published/gigabit-AN.html) for such links. Some of the reasons for that include:

> 55.6.1 Support for Auto-Negotiation
>
> All 10GBASE-T PHYs shall provide support for Auto-Negotiation (Clause 28) and shall be capable of
> operating as MASTER or SLAVE. All 10GBASE-T PHYs shall provide support
> for Extended Next Pages as defined in 28.2.3.4.2 and shall support and
> use optimized FLP Burst to FLP burst timing as defined in 28.2.1.1.1,
> and nlp_link_test_min_timer and link_fail_inhibit_timer as defined in
> 28.3.2.
>
> Auto-Negotiation is performed as part of the initial set-up of the
> link, and allows the PHYs at each end to advertise their capabilities
> (speed, PHY type, half or full duplex) and to automatically select the
> operating mode for communication on the link. Auto-Negotiation
> signaling is used for the following primary purposes for 10GBASE-T:
>
> - To negotiate that the PHY is capable of supporting 10GBASE-T transmission.
> - To determine the MASTER-SLAVE relationship between the PHYs at each end of the link.
> - To determine whether the local PHY performs PMA training pattern reset.
> - To determine whether the local PHY supports the EEE capability.
> - To determine whether the local PHY supports the fast retrain capability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I find that 10GBASE-T link's `autonegotian` can be off as the update. Why is that?